# Unknown code in script

Tags: bash, scripts

I found some code in a script given to me by another person as a resource for lockdown/hardening of Ubuntu 16.04 for a project I am doing.

I have no idea what it does and do no want to run it if I can't identify the change it would make, is anyone aware of what it does or changes? Only code without a brief explanation comment, and it happens to be the only thing I do not know. Also, second function is identifiable by function but I don't understand the purpose or specifics.

```
function bacon.config.ubuntu.chage() {
CHAGE_SCRIPT='/etc/cron.daily/userchage'
if [ ! -e $CHAGE_SCRIPT ]; then
printf "#%c/bin/bash \nfor i in \$(awk -F: '{if(($3 >= 1000)&&($3 <65534)) print \$1}' /etc/passwd); do \nchage -m 0 -M 60 -W 10 \$i \ndone \n" ! > $CHAGE_SCRIPT
    chmod +x $CHAGE_SCRIPT
fi
}

function bacon.config.ubuntu.log.rotate() {
  echo "bacon.config.ubuntu.log.rotate: [INFO] Installing logrotate..."

  sudo apt-get install logrotate 1>/dev/null

  echo "bacon.config.ubuntu.log.rotate: [INFO] Configuring logrotate..."
  sed 's/rotate 4/rotate 60/' /etc/logrotate.conf > /etc/logrotate.conf.new
  mv /etc/logrotate.conf.new /etc/logrotate.conf
  sed 's/rotate 1/rotate 60/' /etc/logrotate.conf > /etc/logrotate.conf.new
  mv /etc/logrotate.conf.new /etc/log.rotate.conf
  sed 's/rotate 7/rotate 1825/' /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog > /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog.new
  mv /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog.new /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
}
```

Any help identifying these would be amazing.

Comment: I would ask the person who gave me the code what it does.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Normally I would as well, but they are away from the office for a while due to personal circumstances. Trust me, I know how much easier that would be. :)

Comment: Well done on **not running a script as root when you don't know what it does.**

Comment: You can always fire up a VM and test! I've always been a try and fail and learn kinda guy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first function checks whether file `$CHAGE_SCRIPT` exists, and if not attempts to create it with a `printf` statement. You can see what this statement does by running it in a terminal:

```
$ printf "#%c/bin/bash \nfor i in \$(awk -F: '{if(($3 >= 1000)&&($3 <65534)) print \$1}' /etc/passwd); do \nchage -m 0 -M 60 -W 10 \$i \ndone \n" !
#!/bin/bash 
for i in $(awk -F: '{if(( >= 1000)&&( <65534)) print $1}' /etc/passwd); do 
chage -m 0 -M 60 -W 10 $i 
done
```

You will notice that instances of `$3` evaluate empty because (unlike `\$1`) they are not protected from expansion by the shell. The use of `%c` to insert the `!` in `#!/bin/bash` suggests the original author doesn't really understand how bash's history expansion works.

IMHO it would be simpler and clearer to use a here-document:

```
function bacon.config.ubuntu.chage() {
CHAGE_SCRIPT='/etc/cron.daily/userchage'
if [ ! -e "$CHAGE_SCRIPT" ]; then
    cat << 'EOF' > "$CHAGE_SCRIPT"
#!/bin/bash 
for i in $(awk -F: '{if(($3 >= 1000)&&($3 <65534)) print $1}' /etc/passwd); do 
chage -m 0 -M 60 -W 10 $i 
done
EOF
    chmod +x "$CHAGE_SCRIPT"
fi
}
```

The operation of the second function should be pretty obvious - it could be simplified by combining all the `sed` commands so that the file is only written / moved once.

Comment: If the $3 evaluates empty, is there a reason to include it? If I wanted something to complete the same task, without useless portions included how much would I need to change it?

Comment: @Brendan77222 I'm assuming the empty evaluation of `$3` was unintentional - since it would result in a syntax error from awk

Comment: would leaving it in or taking it out be something I need to be concerned with? Should I want it to function as intended at least.

Answer (score 4):

The script contains two function definitions. The first function, `bacon.config.ubuntu.chage`, creates a script at `/etc/cron.daily/userchage` (comments added by me):

```
#!/bin/bash
# loop through users with uid >= 1000 and uid < 65534 theoretically, but $3 isn't escaped -> doesn't work
for i in $(awk -F: '{if(( >= 1000)&&( <65534)) print $1}' /etc/passwd);do
    # set password to expire after 60 days, warning after 50 days
    chage -m 0 -M 60 -W 10 $i
done
```

The second function installs [logrotate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_rotation) and creates a config file for it.

Comment: Awesome those comments help a lot. is there a reason for inserting a script at /etc/chron.daily/userchage rather than just executing the for loop you put here? I am unfamiliar with userchage file's function

Comment: Yes, any scripts in /etc/cron.daily/ will be executed once per day.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the confirmation on what I suspected. Awesome help.

Answer (score 2):

The `chage` program changes the password expiry for all users. That is, **it only lets them keep their current password for at most 60 days**. It is run daily. The minimum duration of `0` is questionable as of https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/78758/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-password-minimum-age-setting. Maybe ask on https://security.stackexchange.com if this is really recommended.

Why `logrotate` should improve security is a bit above me.

Comment: Oh, we definitely want a minimum password age of 24 hours. I assume that is the -m flag? I can read the man page as well, just was confused on why it used a check for a script. But I now feel from your comment it does that to ensure this is checked daily rather than a one time thing.

Comment: Exactly. And `-m` seems correct. If you can read the man pages, you can see `man cron` for the `cron.daily` folder.